# IN() select slow in php fast in DB. Rewrite to joins even slower

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

I have a query with 2 sub selects that in the PHP page takes upwards of 20 seconds to process (just to populate a dropdown box!) but when I run the query via phpmyadmin it returns all its results in 0.4 seconds

```
SELECT ID, SupplierName
FROM tblsuppliers
WHERE ID
IN (
SELECT DISTINCT Supplier
FROM tblmovements
WHERE SuppIsDisputed =1
)
OR ID
IN (
SELECT DISTINCT UsedSupplier
FROM tblsundries
WHERE SuppIsDisputed =1
)
ORDER BY SupplierName ASC
```

So I thought well sub selects and IN()'s are slow and expensive I'll rewrite to joins.

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT 
tblsuppliers.ID,
tblsuppliers.SupplierName
 FROM 
tblsuppliers 
LEFT JOIN tblmovements ON tblsuppliers.ID=tblmovements.Supplier 
LEFT JOIN tblsundries ON tblsuppliers.ID=tblsundries.UsedSupplier 
WHERE 
tblmovements.SuppIsDisputed=1
OR
tblsundries.SuppIsDisputed=1
ORDER BY tblsuppliers.SupplierName ASC
```

Using `GROUP BY tblsuppliers.ID` the query takes upwards of 60 seconds even ran in phpmyadmin (page times out) but using distinct it completes but in 20 seconds so still slower than the sub selects when done directly against the DB

So I thought I'd profile the queries.

The sub select query gives me the following when profiled.

```
Status          Time
starting            0.000042
checking permissions0.000004
checking permissions0.000001
checking permissions0.000002
Opening tables  0.000025
System lock     0.000006
init            0.000032
optimizing          0.000006
statistics          0.000007
preparing           0.000007
executing           0.000001
Sorting result  0.000052
optimizing          0.000006
statistics          0.000008
preparing           0.003540
optimizing          0.000012
statistics          0.000010
preparing           0.408007
Sending data    0.000031
end             0.000004
query end           0.000006
closing tables  0.000011
freeing items   0.000085
logging slow query  0.000002
cleaning up     0.000001
```

Explains why its fast in phpmyadmin but doesn't explain why it takes 20 seconds in PHP to run the same query!

The join query gives me the following when profiled.

```
Status          Time
starting            0.000045
checking permissions0.000003
checking permissions0.000001
checking permissions0.000005
Opening tables  0.000027
System lock     0.000006
init            0.000027
optimizing          0.000009
statistics          0.000021
preparing           0.000011
Creating tmp table  0.000132
executing           0.000002
Copying to tmp table20.071386
Sorting result  0.000090
Sending data    0.000019
end             0.000002
removing tmp table  0.000007
end             0.000003
query end           0.000003
closing tables  0.000010
freeing items   0.000087
logging slow query  0.000002
logging slow query  0.000001
cleaning up     0.000001
```

I found that a little wierd it explains the 20 second process time when using distinct.  Not sure how I can improve the time copying to the tmp table?

Based off the above I have the following questions.

1. Is there a better way of rewriting the subselect query to be join
   based or generally faster?
2. Why is the sub select taking only 0.4 seconds when ran in phpmyadmin
   / in mysqlclient but taking ages in php?
3. Is there any way to stop (even if its server setting alterations)
   the copying to tmp table for the join based query taking 20 seconds
   +.
4. Am I just being an idiot?

For reference the block of PHP that generates the drop down is below (using the sub select query)

```
$supplier = $db->query("SELECT ID,SupplierName FROM tblsuppliers WHERE ID IN(SELECT DISTINCT Supplier FROM tblmovements WHERE SuppIsDisputed=1) OR ID IN(SELECT DISTINCT UsedSupplier FROM tblsundries WHERE SuppIsDisputed=1) ORDER BY SupplierName ASC",ENABLE_DEBUG);
        if ($db->numRows($supplier)>0) { 
            while ($suppliers = $db->fetchNextObject($supplier)) {
                $selected = ($suppliers->ID==$_POST['filter']) ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "" ;
                echo "<option value=\"".stripslashes($suppliers->ID)."\" $selected>".stripslashes($suppliers->SupplierName)."</option>";
            }
        }
```

EDIT: explains on queries.

Columns with INDEX and column data types

```
tblmovements.Supplier - type int(10)
tblsundries.UsedSupplier - type int(10)
tblsuppliers.SupplierName - type varchar(200)

tblsuppliers.ID -  type int(10) auto increment primary key
```

The following columns have no index on but are tinyint(1) values of 0 or 1.

```
tblmovements.SuppIsDisputed=1
tblsundries.SuppIsDisputed=1
```

Sub select Explain:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     tblsuppliers    ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1341    Using where; Using filesort
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  tblsundries     index_subquery  UsedSupplier    UsedSupplier    4   func    22  Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  tblmovements    index_subquery  Supplier    Supplier    8   func    157     Using where
```

Join Explain:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  tblsuppliers    ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1403    Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  tblmovements    ref     Supplier    Supplier    8   ggdashboard.tblsuppliers.ID     157     Distinct
1   SIMPLE  tblsundries     ref     UsedSupplier    UsedSupplier    4   ggdashboard.tblsuppliers.ID     22  Using where; Distinct
```

Comment: Its a lot easier to solve performance issues looking at the execution plan. Prepend `EXPLAIN ` to your query. Times in seconds for not very big databases usually mean wrong or no indexes are used.

Comment: I should mention the database is large :) tblsuppliers is only 5k items tblmovements is 1.2 million items tblsundries is 500k items. explains will be up shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the row counts from explain output it seems there are very few rows having  `SuppIsDisputed = 1` in both tables so idexes on these columns would be very selective for this condition. I'd try adding these indexes and rewriting your query as union of two idependent joins, which would result in a filesort only for the ready rowset after applying union, to sort rows by SupplierName, and it would easily fit in the memory because of low row count.

So run this first:

```
ALTER TABLE tblmovements ADD INDEX m_disputed( SuppIsDisputed );
ALTER TABLE tblsundries ADD INDEX s_disputed( SuppIsDisputed );
```

and then use this query in your code:

```
( SELECT DISTINCT s.Id, s.SupplierName FROM tblsuppliers s
JOIN tblmovements m ON s.ID = m.Supplier
WHERE m.SuppIsDisputed = 1 )
UNION
( SELECT DISTINCT s.ID, s.SupplierName FROM tblsuppliers s
JOIN tblsundries sd ON s.ID = sd.UsedSupplier
WHERE sd.SuppIsDisputed = 1 )
ORDER BY SupplierName
```

Comment: OK this is a genuine performance increase 0.1 seconds in phpmyadmin and about 2 seconds in the php script so much much better.  Don't know why i didn't think of using a union before tbh.  I'm going to try to implement the same kind of structure on the other 4 pages with similar queries (different but similar one is across 7 tables so not sure how a union will hold up)

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT ID, SupplierName
FROM tblsuppliers
WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT Supplier
             FROM tblmovements
             WHERE SuppIsDisputed = 1
            ) OR
      ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT UsedSupplier
             FROM tblsundries
             WHERE SuppIsDisputed = 1
            )
ORDER BY SupplierName ASC;
```

I'm going to propose a three-part solution for increasing performance.  First, rewrite the query to use `exists` rather than `in`:

```
SELECT ID, SupplierName
FROM tblsuppliers s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tblmovements m
              WHERE m.SuppIsDisputed = 1 and s.id = m.Supplier
             ) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tblsundries su
              WHERE su.SuppIsDisputed = 1 and s.id = su.UsedSupplier
             )
ORDER BY SupplierName ASC;
```

Second, add indexes on the tables used in the subqueries to make the lookups faster:  `tblmovements(Supplier, SuppIsDisputed)` and `tblsundries(UsedSupplier, SuppIsDisputed)`.

Finally, add an index on the outer query to avoid the final sort:  `tblsuppliers(SupplierName, id)`.

Comment: All index's are already in place as you specified so I'll give the query change a try see what happens.  Any suggestions as to why it would be 0.4 using the sub select direct but in php it'd be slower ?

Comment: OK its a little bit faster than the join but slower than the sub query as it currently exists your version taking: Query took 9.6913 sec thats in phpmyadmin in PHP its still 20 seconds +

Comment: @Dave . . . No, I cannot think of a good reason.  Perhaps you are connected to a different (test) database that has empty tables, or your a measuring the response to the first row returned in one case versus all rows in the second case.  Or, one timing is done on a cold database and the other on a warm database.  Or something else entirely.

Comment: @Dave . . . Can you edit your question with the sizes of the tables and the number of matches  you are expecting for each condition?

Comment: all running direct on test DB (mirror of live dataset though) I did check that first but pio's union seems to have made a massive speed increase so going to go with that for now.  The overall database sizes are up top in a comment I'm expecting about 1700 results from tblmovements and a couple of hundred from tblsundries but with a distinct/grouped select on the supplier id should give me 199 in total returned after filtering. tblmovements is 340mb tblsundries is 85ish mb tblsuppliers is 2mb if you want the exact data sizes :)